# remove default decorator label from the Zend_Form_Element_Radio

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, php

in my zend form after creating a radio button there is label wrapping radio button

```
<label for="type-per"><input type="radio" class="radio" value="per" id="type-per" name="type">Percentage</label>
```

the problem i having is , when i click the wrapping label , not on the button the button is selected , so i want to remove the wrapping label , i don't want to remove all labels in my form . i only want to remove the radio button's wrapping label . this is my radio buttons code ,

```
    $type = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('type');
    $type->setLabel('Type');
    $type->addMultiOption('per', 'Percentage');
    $type->addMultiOption('fix','Fixed');
    $type->setRequired(true);
    $type->removeDecorator('Errors');
    $type->addErrorMessage('You must select a type.');
    $type->class = 'radio';
    $type->setDecorators(
                         array(
                            array('ViewHelper',
                                        array('helper' => 'formRadio')
                            ),
                            array('Label',
                                        array('class' => 'label')
                            ),
                            array(
                                array('out'=>'HtmlTag'),
                                array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'formfield', 'id' => 'type_div')
                             ),
                             array(
                                array('prepend' => 'HtmlTag'),
                                array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'clear', 'placement' => 'prepend')
                             )                                                                                               
                         )                           
                      );
```

please help :(

Answer (score 1):

First of all your set of decorators do not generate the HTML you provided. However

To completely remove the label just remove this line from your set of decorators

```
array('Label', array('class' => 'label') ),
```

but it will remove the text too

you could also try

```
array('Label', 
      array('class' => 'label',
           'placement'=>'APPEND',
           'tag'=>'span', //if you want to use other tag
           'disableFor'=>true) 
     ),
```

probably `'disableFor'=>true` is what you need, because it removes the `for` attribute of the `label` which is responsible for activating the `input` when clicked on the `label`.

Third way is to use a custom decorator that only appends text (you can use Label decorator for base and replace `355. $label = $view->formLabel($element->getFullyQualifiedName(), trim($label), $options);` with your code)

As a side note: You also do not need `$type->removeDecorator('Errors');` because when you use `setDecorators` later it will first remove all decorators (including `Errors`) then add the new ones you listed, and if you omit `'Errors'` it will not be added.